# Executing command C# Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line, command

I have a program where I want to do the following:

1. Get a file (type unknown)
2. Save file locally
3. Execute some command (unknown) on the file

I have step 1 and 2 taken care of but I am struggling on step 3. I use the following code:

**NOTE:** The file type and command are just used for testing

```
//Redirects output
procStart.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
procStart.UseShellExecute = true;
procStart.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Test\\System_Instructions.txt";
procStart.Arguments = "mkdir TestDir";

//No black window
procStart.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process.Start(procStart);
```

The `.txt` document will open, but the command will not be run (there will be no `testDir` in the `test` folder)

Suggestions?

Comment: Where are you getting that error from?  This is definitely an exception originating from a compiled line of code, not a statement entered in the immediate window?

Comment: I'm with Kragen on this one: that error usually means you've viewed something in the locals or watch window, or inspected an expression via the immediate window. I assume you're doing that because the code is otherwise not working, but I don't think that error message is your actual problem.

Comment: @Keragan - I get the error on the `Response.End()` line when I run the program in my debugger, I removed the line like @Davide suggested I don't get any errors, but the directory is not created

Comment: What kind of program is this? (`Response.End()` suggests ASP.NET, but I'd prefer not to assume.)

Comment: @dlev - It is a asp.net program. The method is being run on pageload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your `Process` isn't setup properly.

Your current code will open a .txt file using the default .txt file opener (since you specified `procStart.UseShellExecute = true;`) You then set `procStart.Arguments = "mkdir TestDir";` But that's not actually going to help you, since all that will happen is `"mkdir TestDir"` will be passed as command-line arguments to `notepad.exe`.

What you really want is either:

1. A separate `ProcessStartInfo` with the `FileName` set to `cmd.exe` (and set `Arguments = "/C mkdir Test"`)
2. Use the [`CreateDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) method directly.

I would prefer #2, since it more clearly shows what you'd like to do, but either should work.

**UPDATE**: If you need to use option 1, then you should use the following code to see what's going wrong:

```
Process userCommandProc = Process.Start(procStart);
userCommandProc.WaitForExit();

if (userCommandProc.ExitCode != 0)
{
    // Something has (very likely) gone wrong
}
else
{
    // Most likely working
}
```

A couple other notes:

1. This process will be run on the server, not the client computer. If you need the latter, you're out of luck if you want to use a web app.
2. This kind of processing is probably better left to a standard `.ashx` handler then a web page; page loads should be as snappy as possible.

Comment: I am trying to do the first thing that you mentioned (since I will not know what the command is going to be. I have edited my code to the following: `ProcessStartInfo procStart = new ProcessStartInfo(); procStart.RedirectStandardOutput = false; procStart.FileName = "cmd.exe"; procStart.Arguments = "/C mkdir TestDir"; procStart.CreateNoWindow = true; Process.Start(procStart);` but the directory is still not created

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran the code you have added and I got an ExitCode of '1' so there is something wrong with the code. I am going to have to do some more research to see what is going wrong

Comment: I keep getting an `System.InvalidOperatinException`. Any idea why? I switched the code over to my .ashx class also.

Comment: @Peppered when do you get that exception?

Comment: When I run the debugger and watch `userCommandProc` after the `userCommandProc.WaitForExit();` line. The exception is thrown by `userCommandProc`

Comment: Making the application as a Console application doesn't change the issue either

Comment: Actually the folder was made, just not where I thought it was. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+optimized+or+a+native+frame+is+on+top+of+the+call+stack

you should not call `Response.End` like that because this terminates it.